# React native vector icon not working on current version 0.60

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-vector-icons

React native autolink not working for react native vector icons. I fixed this into android with this 
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1035

But on IOS i am still facing issues. Please let me know if anyone solved this...Thanks!

Here is screenshot what issue i am facing.

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This worked for me on an upgraded project and on a brand new RN 0.60.0

For IOS add this to ios/projectname/Info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

For Android add this line to android/app/build.gradle

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

That is fixed my issues and react native vector icons working in both the platform.

Comment: After doing this I am getting the following error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons") . I am using RN V0.62.2

Comment: Thanks for this answer, was looking for this from hrs.. realy helpful..

Comment: Glad to know the answer is helping you.

Answer (score 4):

If you did `react-native link` on iOS do `cd ios` and then `pod install`.

Some packages still need to be updated by the maintainers  to work with react native.

Aniway, if you dont wanna link go inside your podfile and add:

```
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

after that do the same steps i said before

Comment: React native 0.60 is providing autolink we can't do react-native link it cause errors.

Comment: Some packages are still not updated for RN 0.60. I'll edit my question

Comment: I added and update pod file, Clear build folder and run but still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
npx react-native link
```

at root folder project to resolve this problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Fonts, images, and other external assets should still be linked by using **react-native link** command, which is the only reason why the command still exists.

However, the configuration to link assets changed, once in the past it was by placing a rnpm entry in package.json with the paths to be linked. Check [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md).

The correct way now to have fontawesome linked is to have a **react-native.config.js** file.

1 - Create a **react-native.config.js** file

```
 module.exports = {
      project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
      },
      assets: [
        './node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/PATH_TO_FONT_A',
        './node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/PATH_TO_FONT_B',
      ],
    };
```

2 - run command

```
react-native link
```

This time, now, the link command will produce a log message such as

```
info Linking assets to ios project
warn Group 'Resources' does not exist in your Xcode project. We have created it automatically for you.
info Linking assets to android project
success Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

Comment: Adding just some fonts from `node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts` to `assets` array does not exclude all the other ones. How to exclude unnecessary fonts from `react-native-vector-icons`?

Answer (score -2):

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

**Icon.loadFont();**

try this